# Erro ao usar usar método da classe QLabel - PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt-5

Tô tentando criar uma aplicação que faz o seguinte: todas as vezes que o usuário clicar sobre uma imagem que ficará dentro de um QLabel, ele abrirá um diálogo para o usuário abrir outra imagem.

Acontece que dá dando o seguinte erro o método setPixmap no construtor da classe HandlerWindow:

```
self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap("imagem.jpg").scaled(250,150, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
NameError: name 'QPixmap' is not defined
```

Código completo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit,
                            QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox, QRadioButton, QGroupBox,
                            QVBoxLayout,QLabel)

class CustomLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        img, re = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Selecionar Arquivo", filter="All(*.png *.jpg)")
        if re:
            self.setPixmap(QPixmap(img).scaled(250, 150, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

class HandlerWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HandlerWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(300,350)
        self.label = CustomLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap("imagem.jpg").scaled(250,150, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

    def leaveEvent(self, e):
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        e.ignore()
        question_close = QMessageBox.question(self, "Fechamento", "Deseja realmente fechar a aplicação?",
                                              QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)
        if question_close == QMessageBox.Yes:
            exit(0)

root = QApplication([])
app = HandlerWindow()
app.show()
sys.exit(root.exec_())
```

EDIT:

Tem QPixmap na classe Qt tb. Tentei aqui e cheguei no mesmo resultado do que usando a classe QtGui. Ele tá abrindo a primeira imagem e ao clicar na imagem ele abre abre o explorer pra eu pegar uma nova imagem pra ser visualizada, porém não tá mudando a imagem do cursor ao passar ele pela imagem

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit,
                            QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox, QRadioButton, QGroupBox,
                            QVBoxLayout,QLabel,QFileDialog)

from PyQt5.Qt import (Qt,QPixmap)

import sys

class CustomLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        img, re = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Selecionar Arquivo", filter="All(*.png *.jpg)")
        if re:
            self.setPixmap(QPixmap(img).scaled(800, 800, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

class HandlerWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HandlerWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(800,650)
        self.label = CustomLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap("imagem.jpg").scaled(800,800, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

    def leaveEvent(self, e):
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)


root = QApplication([])
app = HandlerWindow()
app.show()
sys.exit(root.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O QPixmap é da QtGui:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QPixmap)
                         ^^^^^^^
```

Mesmo que usado indiretamente, o Py precisa do respectivo `import`. A PyQt é um *wrapper* para a implementação em C++, e precisa "conhecer" as camadas que fazem a adaptação de cada uma das classes.

Aproveitando, poderia ser o caso de usar uma variável intermediária, caso vá reaproveitar a imagem (se bem que a Qt lida bem internamente com essas situações):

```
pix = QPixmap("imagem.jpg")
self.label.setPixmap(pix.scaled(250,150, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
```

Vale lembrar que no caso de usar muitas classes, pode fazer algo assim (cada caso é um caso, claro) mas teria que ficar prefixando as classes:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```